# Google Query SELECT statement concatenated with a NESTED IF result

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to return a Nested IF result from a CELL that will be concatenated to the SELECT statement in the QUERY function?

For example, I am trying to return the result for the following Nested IF function into the Query Function:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15i1E8AZHORRmPlu1VQqFRN1_7-aUyAz-hlYMOUtIlY4/edit?usp=sharing

Appreciate it, if anyone could take a look.

Regards
JVA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its done like this:

```
=QUERY(TESTDATA!A1:D16, "SELECT A, D, SUM(C) WHERE 1=1 "&
 IF(AND(M3="NAME",N3="Customer"), " GROUP BY A, D PIVOT B", 
 IF(AND(N3 = "Customer"," AND A = '"&M3&"' GROUP BY A, D PIVOT B"), 
                        " AND A = '"&M3&"' GROUP BY A, D PIVOT B",
                        " AND A = '"&M3&"' 
                          AND D = '"&N3&"' GROUP BY A, D PIVOT B")), 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it's easier to `FILTER` the results before applying `QUERY`:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(FILTER(A1:D16, A1:A16=M3, D1:D16=N3), "SELECT Col1, Col4, SUM(Col3) GROUP BY Col1, Col4 PIVOT Col2 LABEL Col1 'Name', Col4 'Customer'",0))`

As you can see, this requires using Colx notation instead of letters to indicate columns in the `SELECT` clause; but this is actually (in my opinion) more versatile, since you don't have to rewrite the `QUERY` if you ever insert columns before the existing source data.

You'll also notice that I needed to `LABEL` the first two columns, since `FILTER` will have `FILTER`ed out the headers. (In fact, for this reason, the ranges in the formula could just as easily have begun with row 2, e.g., `A2:A16`, etc.)

Finally, at least in your sample spreadsheet, you didn't need the sheet name to reference the source ranges, since the result is in the same sheet.